# Python subprocess.check_output conver to windows

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, zgrep

I wrote some code that works fine on a Linux machine but does not run on windows.

```
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

def zgrep_data(f, string='', index='TIMESTAMP'):
    if string == '':
        out = subprocess.check_output(['zgrep', string, f])
        grep_data = StringIO(out)    
        data= pd.read_csv(grep_data, sep=',', header=0)

    else:
        col_out = subprocess.check_output(['zgrep', index, f])
        col_data = StringIO(col_out)
        columns = list(pd.read_csv(col_data, sep=','))

        out = subprocess.check_output(['zgrep', string, f])
        grep_data = StringIO(out)    
        data= pd.read_csv(grep_data, sep=',',names=columns, header=None)

    return data.set_index(index).reset_index()
```

I'm getting an error: 
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

When I check it it with os.path.exists(file_path), it returns true. Any advice on how to modify this code so that it works on both Python 2 & 3 plus Windows and Linux would be appreciated.

Comment: `zgrep` isn't in your path. this isn't a standard windows command, so you have to find a windows version and install it... That's the only explanation to the error. which file are you checking? what is `file_path` ?

Comment: The file is on my c drive. C:/Users/Chris/Documents/massivefile.csv

Comment: So filepath would be f in the function

Comment: have you read my first comment? this isn't about your data file.

Answer (score 0):

this message only means one thing: the executable could not be found.

this has nothing to do with your data file, since the process isn't even run.

And why that? because while `zgrep` is standard on Linux, it's a third party port on Windows, so you have to install it first from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/)

Note that if you only want to grep a string on csv files, it's overkill to use `zgrep`. It's much better to use a native python approach, reading lines (or rows, using the `csv` module) and matching patterns. You can even open `.gz` files natively. Then it will *really* be portable.